# Showing 'back' button with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an iPhone application with HTML5, CSS, and jQuery using PhoneGap. However, there seem to be some problems with either my understanding of PhoneGap or the MWE.

I used following code from codeforest.net:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile Tutorial on Codeforest.net</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Start of first page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="first">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>First</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>The content</p>
                <p>View internal page called <a href="#second">second</a></p>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div><!-- /page -->


        <!-- Start of second page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="second">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Second</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>I'm the second content</p>
                <p><a href="#first">Back to first</a></p>   
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Starting the code in its separate file will result in the wanted behavior (only shows first `div` with `id="first"`, when clicking on the link the second page is loaded with a back button on top).

I thought I could just use PhoneGap to convert this HTML/CSS/JS example to working iOS application.

The problem I had from the beginning was that I want to have several different `.html` files, which reference each other. This works, but has the problem that no native `back-button` is shown in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as posted by the original questioner (as an update to the question--I've moved it to here so it's in an answer):

> Problem was that the app couldn't load code from external links.
>   Solution found here: [External links or url doesn't work on phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752732/external-links-or-url-doesnt-work-on-phonegap)

Answer (score 3):

Then create a back button of your own.

This part of code will create a back button for you:

```
<a class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="arrow-l" href="javascript:history.back(1) " data-theme="a">Back</a>
```

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ddsrx/. It is using one file with multiple pages but it will also work with a few separate html files.

Comment: The actual problem was that the new PhoneGap requires a whitelist of external links, otherwise it won't load the external files (in my case all files from code.jquery.com).